How do I add a web gl hover effect to a container?
I want the image to fit in my container like an object-fit cover and not take the space of whole viewport width. I took inspirations for the effect from this website.


.casestart {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imageside {
  width: 52vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: #000;
}

  canvas{
  width: 52vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index:1;
  }

  img{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  }
<div class="casestart">
  <div class="imageside">
    <img id="hoverImage" src="https://www.datocms-assets.com/92457/1676542990-mvsm_logitechquake2_explode01_v001_b.jpg?fit=max&fm=jpg&h=1920&w=1920" alt="" draggable="false" srcset="">
  </div>
</div>



I've tried everything man. It doesn't work.

your site is dead, can you attach the real image path?

Could you describe in more detail exactly what you want because at the moment my question is: if you want it to look like object-fit: cover, why not use object-fit: cover? Also please make a working snippet (it needs an image we can see).

Looking at the linked site you provided, they are using canvas and I don't see anything in the code you have given that would create the effects they have there. What are you actually asking? Simply how to keep an img within a container which is less than the viewport or how to create those hover effects (which are a lot more complex in terms of required code!)

You cant just use object fit cover because the effect I need involves rendering the image in a canvas on top of the initial container as canvas will have a higher z index than the initial container.

and yeah the effect is really complex. Ive tried something similar with OOP but it slowed down the whole page and I'm looking for a lighter version using web gl

canvas doesn’t appear in the HTML you have provided, nor is there any info on how you are rendering the image onto a canvas so your question is currently not complete. As it stands object-fit will fit the img to its container, canvas doesn’t come into it.

yeahh thats what Im saying I dont know how to do that. Thanks for answering.



.casestart {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imageside {
  width: 52vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: #000;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
<div class="casestart">
  <div class="imageside">
    <img id="hoverImage" src="12.webp" alt="" draggable="false" srcset="">
  </div>
</div>



